# MEDIPS Package by Lukas Chavez

Tags: r

I'm running a few quality controls using the most up-to-date `MEDIPS` package on my MacBook Air OS X El Capitan with 4GB of memory. I'm able to run the other quality controls: saturation analysis and sequence pattern coverage nicely. However this is the error I receive after running a CpG enrichment check. The file I ran it on is around 3GB and I only selected chr1:

```
er = MEDIPS.CpGenrich(file=file,BSgenome=BSgenome, chr.select = chr.select, extend = extend,uniq = uniq)
Reading bam alignment HCB3_45Low_merged_unique.bam 
Selecting chr1 
Total number of imported short reads: 3214352
Extending reads...
Creating GRange Object...
Keep at most one 1 read mapping to the same genomic location.
Number of remaining reads: 3211326
Loading chromosome lengths for BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19...
Calculating CpG density for given regions...

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x7fff4c68f380, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: .Call(.NAME, ..., PACKAGE = PACKAGE)
2: .Call2("new_CHARACTER_from_XStringSet", x, xs_dec_lkup(x), PACKAGE = "Biostrings")
3: .local(x, ...)
4: as.character(ans)
5: as.character(ans)
6: .local(x, ...)
7: getSeq(dataset, names = space(x), start = start(x), end = end(x), as.character = TRUE)
8: getSeq(dataset, names = space(x), start = start(x), end = end(x), as.character = TRUE)
```

I haven't found a solid answer online, but is this R's way of telling me I ran out of memory or a bug with `Biostrings`? I've updated `Biostings` prior to running this.

Let me know what you think. I'm very new to R programming, so simplifying would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a question about a Bioconductor package, so should be addressed to the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org). It looks like a problem with Biostrings, so be sure to tag your question with 'MEDIPS' and 'Biostrings'. My guess would be that your packages are not in sync; run the command `BiocInstaller::biocValid()`. Also, be sure to use current versions of R and Bioconductor; report the output of `sessionInfo()` after loading MEDIPS (but before segfaulting!).

Comment: after I loaded MEDIPS, I did sessionInfo() and the program worked! From my understanding, this just prints out the version of R and bioconductor and the packages...does it tell MEDIPS something so it doesnt crash? Thanks a lot for the help by way, made my Friday!

Comment: If you did not update your packages, then you are probably just lucky and it will segfault again in the future.

Comment: So I did update limma package, but it didn't run.  It ran after updating limma and when I put sessionInfo().

Comment: At the end of the day you want to report a bug. To be useful, the bug report needs to include a reproducible example. A reproducible example will use a current version of R and relevant packages, a script that starts from a new R session and ends with the bug, the data required to run the script (else how will someone else be able to run the commands?), and the output of `sessionInfo()` after all packages are loaded but before the error occurs. The bug needs to be reported to the `packageMaintainer("Biostrings")`, or to the appropriate [support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Answer (score 0):

What i've met was that the error would happend when the version of Biostrings is 2.48.0 and disappeared when the version is 2.50.2.